# How to compute the conditional probability of Xn given the initial value, using the transition matrix?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $p \in ]0,1[$ and $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ be a Markov chain on E:={a,b,c} with transition matrix

$Q:=\begin{pmatrix}
1-p & p & 0 \\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

I should compute $\mathbb{P}(X_n=b|X_0=a)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and further the limit of it for $n \to \infty$.

I tried to use that $Q^n(a,b)=(Q^{n-1}\cdot Q)(a,b)$.

So I have: $\mathbb{P}(X_n=b|X_0=a)=(1-p)\mathbb{P}(X_{n-1}=b|X_0=a)+p\cdot \mathbb{P}(X_{n-1}=b|X_0=b)$ as I can only get from a to b...

I defined $a_{n}=\mathbb{P}(X_n=b|X_0=a)$
and $a_{n-1}=\mathbb{P}(X_{n-1}=b|X_0=a)$ and $b_{n-1}=\mathbb{P}(X_{n-1}=b|X_0=b)$. Further I have the initial values $a_0=1$ and $a_1=p$.
If I'm in b I have to go back to a to able to go to b again... so $ b_{n-1}=1/2 \cdot a_{n-2}$.

Therefore I have the equation $a_n=(1-p) \cdot a_{n-1}+p/2 \cdot a_{n-2}$.

Unfortunately I don't know how to solve this equation using the initial condition. Am I on the right track? And what condition would I have to use to continue here?

Comment: Let's say the states are 1,2,3. If i,j are two of those then $P (X_n=j|X_n=i) $ is just $e_i Q^n $ where $e_i $ is the $i $th standard basis vector (as a row vector). That might be hard to simplify for arbitrary n...you would need to diagonalize Q, which can be done but seems messy.

Comment: As for computing the limit, think probabilistically. In particular notice that you have an absorbing state...